# Laravel artisan migrate failed due to authentication failure

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel in my project and MongoDB as the database. As I am performing `php artisan migrate` command the following error occurs

```
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\AuthenticationException  : Authentication failed.

  at /home/mailify/smtp-api/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Command/ListCollections.php:115
    111|         if (isset($this->options['nameOnly'])) {
    112|             $cmd['nameOnly'] = $this->options['nameOnly'];
    113|         }
    114| 
  > 115|         $cursor = $server->executeReadCommand($this->databaseName, new Command($cmd), $this->createOptions());
    116|         $cursor->setTypeMap(['root' => 'array', 'document' => 'array']);
    117| 
    118|         return new CachingIterator($cursor);
    119|     }

  Exception trace:

  1   MongoDB\Driver\Server::executeReadCommand("smtp", Object(MongoDB\Driver\Command), [])
      /home/mailify/smtp-api/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Command/ListCollections.php:115

  2   MongoDB\Command\ListCollections::execute(Object(MongoDB\Driver\Server))
      /home/mailify/smtp-api/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/ListCollections.php:76

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

and this is what is stored (for database) in my .env file of the project

```
DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=27017
DB_DATABASE=admin
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password_root

MONGODB_URL=localhost
MONGODB_USERNAME=smtp
MONGODB_USER=smtp
MONGODB_PASSWORD=
MONGODB_DATABASE=smtp
MONGODB_AUTH_DATABASE=password_mailify
MONGODB_PORT=27017
```

I have searched the issue and tried `php artisan config:clear`  and other stuff but getting the same error again

Comment: Is your mongodb information really listed as "smtp"?

Comment: yes the db name which is used for storing data is smtp

Comment: Can you post your database config @JonasBoshen?

Comment: Change your database config files and put hard code your credentials there, if it succeeds it is a caching issue.

Comment: `# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.`

Comment: this is my /etc/mongod.conf file